# Why do Ekiga touchtones only work with the RFC2833 setting?

Tags: voip, sip

I have Ekiga acting as a softphone for my VOIP account.  I made a call to an automated switchboard which required me to "press 2 to continue".  I attempted to press "2" on the keypad pane but the DTMF or "touch tone" sound was not sent and I could not continue with the switchboard.

Interestingly, when I call my own cellphone I can hear DTMF tones being sent.

How can I get DTMF/touch tones to work with all switchboards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DTMF are dual-tone analogic tones, analogic phones can send/transport/receive them easily because the tones are in a frequency range that phone systems are capable to handle.

VoIP systems are different, they use *codecs* to convert voice to data packages.

Some of the codecs don't *compress* audio but most of them do.

When you take some audio (usually human voice), compress it to make it pass through an IP network and on the other side decompress it, the result is not exactly the same as the original. 
However our hearing organs are very tolerant and are able to identify voices, and human speech although it has been slightly modified.

in the case of DTMF tones, for example: the key **2** is the mix of the frequencies *1336 Hz* and *697 Hz*. If we pass it through compressing and uncompressing the final result won't be the same two frequencies making it impossible for the receiving side to understand which key was pressed.

There are 3 ways to overcome this problem on VoIP systems:

- **In-Band**: Send the tones as-is. Only works with non-compressing codecs.(G.711)
- **SIP Info**: Send the DTMF tones as events in the SIP path.
- **RFC2833**: Send the tones as data in the voice path.

RFC2833 is the recommended way in most cases.

To make it work, your *softphone*, the *PBX* and the *client* receiving the tones must be set to RFC2833. Mixing won't work and most systems are unable to auto-detect the method you're using.

Comment: Very nice answer, thanks.  Does this mean that if the PBX and the client do not have the same setting then there is nothing I can configure which will make it work?

Comment: Yes. That's true. PBX and clients must be on the same setting.

Comment: I'd like to see the official docs match or exceed this answer in terms of quality, well done.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the "Edit -> Preferences -> Protocols -> SIP Settings -> DTMF mode" to "RFC2833" and then it worked on a subsequent call.